# What's the proper way to define a `model` in Node.js using MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, express

```
mongoose = require 'mongoose'

class Locations
  constructor: @(host, port) ->
    @db = new mongoose 'locations', new Server(host, port, {auto_reconnect: true}, {})
    this.db.open ->
    null

  getAll: (callback) ->
    @db.collection 'locations', (err, locations_collection) ->
      if err?
        callback err
      else
        callback null, locations_collection
      null

exports.Locations = Locations
```

I have that in a file called `locations.coffee` and in my `app.js`, I have

```
locationsModel = require '../models/locations'
locationModel = new locationsModel 'localhost', 27017
```

But apparently it never gets instantiated because I get

```
node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
ReferenceError: host is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not seen that method of defining models using Mongoose before.

Have you tried using their [model definition guide](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/model-definition.html)? Converting it to Coffeescript should be relatively easy.

Comment: I guess the question I then have is which files to put everything in.